# Create a function that will test if we can create an object based on the Form class, while passing 2 parameters to it

Tags: php, phpunit

i just started learning php i am taking a course and i was given the task to create several functions one of them should check if we can create an object based on the Form class, while passing it only 2 parameters.

I can't figure out how it should be implemented, please tell me how can I implement it.

Comment: Any update from your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Form` class, you can have variable length param and inside the constructor you can check if count size of arguments is exactly 2 or not like below.

**Form.php:**

```
<?php

class Form{
    public $login, $pass;
    function __construct(...$args){
        if(count($args) != 2){
            throw new \Exception("Parameters' count doesn't match!!");
        }
        $this->login = $args[0];
        $this->pass = $args[1];
    }

   // rest of your code
}
```

---

Then in your PHPUnit test case file, you can check if exception was thrown and assert error messages accordingly. Use [`expectExceptionMessage()`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html?highlight=expectException#testing-exceptions) to assert your exception message.

**FormTest.php:**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

use App\Form; // your Form class namespace path here
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class FormTest extends TestCase{
   public function testwithNoParam(): void{
      $this->expectExceptionMessage("Parameters' count doesn't match!!");
      $o = new Form();
   }

   public function testwithOneParam(): void{
      $this->expectExceptionMessage("Parameters' count doesn't match!!");
      $o = new Form("Test");
   }

   public function testwithTwoParams(): void{
      $o = new Form("Test", "test123");
      $this->assertTrue($o instanceOf Form);
   }

   public function testwithThreeOrMoreParams(): void{
      $this->expectExceptionMessage("Parameters' count doesn't match!!");
      $o = new Form(range(1, rand(3, 1000)));
   }
}
```

**Output Snapshot:**

[image]